# Windows Phone 8 Bing Translator API

Tags: c#, http, authentication, windows-phone-8

I'm using Bing Translator API and Access Token from Windows Azure Marketplace , and I got the language code defined in the app

It works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't and it throws an error like this :

**An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code**

I changed the access token twice (clientId, clientSecret), it works at first then starts showing this exception once again , I've searched everywhere and I can't find a solution for it here's the code used :

```
private void TranslationReady(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   try
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);

            System.IO.Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader streamRead = new System.IO.StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

            System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xTranslation =
              System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(responseString);
            string strTest = xTranslation.Root.FirstNode.ToString();

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => TextBlock2.Text = strTest);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {

            var status = e.Status;
            var response = e.Response;
            var msg = e.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(status.ToString() + response.ToString() + msg.ToString());
        }

        }
```

Comment: where specifically in this code is the exception thrown?  You're catching a WebException so I presume it's being thrown elsewhere?

Comment: It's thrown here : HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;